# WP Подсчитать количество знаков в посте и записать в переменную?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть задача в произвольное поле в переменную word_count каждый раз при сохранении записывать количество знаков в текущей записи (убрав все пробелы и прочий мусор) / Вот код в function.php

```
add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata'); /* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata($post_id)
{
    function str_word_count_utf8($str)
    {
        $a = preg_split('/\W+/u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        return count($a);
    }

    if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] )
    {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) return;
    }
    else { if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return; }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['post_content']) ) { return; }

    $mydata = str_word_count_utf8( ($_POST['post_content']) );

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'word_count', $mydata);

}
```

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так что оно вылетает с критической ошибкой при нажатии сохранить запись; Может кто-то подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо использовать вложенные функции в php. Они объявляются, когда управление доходит до строки, содержащей сигнатуру этой функции. В вашем случае - при первом входе во внешнюю функцию `myplugin_save_postdata`. При повторном заходе туда, будет произведена попытка объявить `str_word_count_utf8` второй раз с неизбежным фаталом.

А хук `save_post` может срабатывать несколько раз при сохранении поста.

Вынесите `str_word_count_utf8` вовне `myplugin_save_postdata`.

Comment: критическую ошибку теперь не показывает, сохранение происходит, но вот после сохранения отображается белый экран, подскажите, пожалуйста как это поправить ?

Comment: Не знаю, я не могу дистанционно отлаживать ваш сайт.

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.